# get autoGenerate key after insert by room and rx java

Tags: rx-java2, android-room, rx-android

I'm new to `rxjava` and room, I have just read some tutorial and they said: `Single<Long> or Maybe<Long>` — where the value emitted on `onSuccess` is the row id of the item inserted.

So I'm trying to do something with room like this and I don't known how can get row id(autoGenerate id) after insert new row in the table.

```
Dao.class

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Single<Long> insert(User user);
```

Repository.class

```
public Single<Long> insertUser(User user) {
        return userDao.insert(user);
    }
```

viewmodel.class

```
saleRepository.insertUser(user).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new SingleObserver<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Long aLong) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Getting row id only makes sense in the context of your User entity design. Please provide it if you're interested in answer.

Comment: I want to use that generated id to add to other row in other table(ForeignKey)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand corectly you want to:

1. insert a user
2. and then call another repository with the id of newly created user to insert something else.

If that's the case you can do something like that:

```java
saleRepository.insertUser(user)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(newlyCreatedUserId -> otherRepository.insert(...))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(newlyCreatedIdByOtherRepository -> /* show something on UI */)
```

For the last statement(`subscribe`) you can use many of the available blocking on nonblocking methods depending on your needs.

Hope it helps :)